# Determining DH parameters strength of a SSL server?

Tags: python, ssl

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ssllabs.com&s=173.203.82.166

Take a look at the grey text in the Cipher Suites section. I would like to find out what is the minimum strength of DH parameter that a server supported? This will be combined with Public key size to calculate the SSL score based on the [Qualys's Server Rating Guide](https://www.ssllabs.com/projects/rating-guide/).

How can I do this using python?